# jQuery click remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code is including the label text in a span tag, what I am trying to do is: remove the span tag when I click in each span.

sample I added test1 and test2, so in **Refined by:** if I click in each label test1 remove that label test1 or if I click in test2 remove the label test2.

someone can help me with that, I am not understanding what I am doing wrong.

```js
var increment2 = 1;
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
  var $li = $(this).parent('li').get(0);
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#selected_items').append('<span class="label label-primary" selected-item="' + $li.id + '_selected">' + $($li).find('label').text() + '</span>');
  } else {
    $('#selected_items > span[selected-item^="' + $li.id + '"]').remove();
  }
  $("span").bind("click", function() {
    alert("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.");
    $(span).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
  <li style="text-indent: 0px;">
    <a id="selected_items">Refined by:</a>
  </li>
  <div class="collapse-link">
    <a aria-controls="collapseCommittee" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-target="#collapseCommittee" data-toggle="collapse">click bellow to include</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="bill-type">
    <li id="item1">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="">test1</label>
      <span for="" class="pull-right">222</span>
    </li>
    <li id="item2">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="">test2</label>
      <span for="" class="pull-right">33</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: You just want to remove label or the `<li>` itself ?

Comment: Do you have your `span` saved into a variable? as you just have the word 'span' written with no reference

Comment: I want remove the whole span: <span class="label label-primary" selected-item="item1_selected">test1</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var increment2 = 1;
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
  var $li = $(this).parent('li').get(0);
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#selected_items').append('<span class="label label-primary" selected-item="' + $li.id + '_selected">' + $($li).find('label').text() + '</span>');
  } else {
    $('#selected_items > span[selected-item^="' + $li.id + '"]').remove();
  }
  $("span").bind("click", function() {
    alert("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.");
    $(this).remove();
    var selectedText = $(this).attr('selected-item');
    selectedText = selectedText.split('_');
    $('li#' + selectedText[0]).find('input').prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
  <li style="text-indent: 0px;">
    <a id="selected_items">Refined by:</a>
  </li>
  <div class="collapse-link">
    <a aria-controls="collapseCommittee" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-target="#collapseCommittee" data-toggle="collapse">click bellow to include</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="bill-type">
    <li id="item1">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="">test1</label>
      <span for="" class="pull-right">222</span>
    </li>
    <li id="item2">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="">test2</label>
      <span for="" class="pull-right">33</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
$('#selected_items').on('click', '.label-primary', function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but did not work: I want remove this after click in the tag: <span class="label label-primary" selected-item="item1_selected">test1</span>

Comment: yes very good, it is what I am looking for, but I need uncheck the checkbox too after remove understand? I need be able to include this again.

Comment: Can you accept this answer as it the answer to your post ?

Comment: @Raduken - Well, you can take a look at my answer below. it removes as well as unchecks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to added click event for particular spam element:

```
  //Assign click to current checked input sibling span
  $(this).parent().find("span").bind("click", function() {
    alert("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.");
    //Remove current li clicked span with this
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
```

```js
var increment2 = 1;
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
  var $li = $(this).parent('li').get(0);
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#selected_items').append('<span class="label label-primary" selected-item="' + $li.id + '_selected">' + $($li).find('label').text() + '</span>');
  } else {
    $('#selected_items > span[selected-item^="' + $li.id + '"]').remove();
  }
  $(this).parent().find("span").bind("click", function() {
    alert("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.");
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
  <li style="text-indent: 0px;">
    <a id="selected_items">Refined by:</a>
  </li>
  <div class="collapse-link">
    <a aria-controls="collapseCommittee" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-target="#collapseCommittee" data-toggle="collapse">click bellow to include</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="bill-type">
    <li id="item1">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="">test1</label>
      <span for="" class="pull-right">222</span>
    </li>
    <li id="item2">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="">test2</label>
      <span for="" class="pull-right">33</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```